# How to hide / disable / capture click event of outlook mail send button?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

Is there an easy way to disable , hide and capture the event of click of outlook mail send button ? The solution has to be compatible with outlook 2007 and 2010 versions. Code examples will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860969(v=office.15).aspx) event of the MailItem class which is fired when the user selects the Send action for an item. Also you may find the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class helpful. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

To disable or hide the button you may consider using a form region which can override the whole inspector region leaving the ribbon control intact (the Replace-all region type). See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information. Also you may consider using [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php).